# How to eagerly load all relationships in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the following model:

```
class Item(Base):
    a = relationship(<whatever>)
    b = relationship(<whatever>)
    c = relationship(<whatever>)
    d = relationship(<whatever>)
    other_stuff = Column(<whatever>)
```

Most of the time, I just want to see the `other_stuff` column, so I don't specify `lazy='joined'` in the relationship. But sometimes, I want to see all the joined fields, and I want them to be loaded in one SQL query. I could do the following:

```
query(Item).options(joinedload('a')).options(joinedload('b')).options(joinedload('c')).options(joinedload('d'))
```

But I feel like this is a common enough use case that there has to be a prettier way to do it.

Comment: Why not just create a helper (static) method on Item: `def query_with_all(cls): return session.query(cls).options(...)...`?

Comment: If I have to turn on joined loads for each property individually, I would definitely implement it that way. But I was hoping that method was already done in SQLalchemy. Looks like it isn't, as far as I can tell (and judging by the lack of responses here)

Comment: I am not aware of this being implemented for `relationship` in a way similar to [`undefer_group`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.undefer_group) on `columns`.

Answer (score 12):

You can simply say `.options(joinedload('*'))`.

For reference:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#wildcard-loading-strategies